# Absolute path of a child element within nested structure

Tags: nested, abap

I want to get the path (from parent to child node) of a structure that is nested. Is it even possible to do it in ABAP?

[image: table]

For example, for `column 1` I want to get: `lt_Structure-table1-tableA-field1`, for `tableA` I want to get: `lt_Structure-table1-tableA`.

I have multiple fields and a couple of nested structures in those columns so it has to be a dynamic solution, have any of you came across something similar?

I need to get all of the values from the structure and I do not see any other way than:

```
ASSIGN (lt_Structure-table1-tableA-field1) TO <fs_value_of_the_field1>.
```

The part inside brackets needs to change dynamically.

Comment: Please don't duplicate your own question, just edit it. [How to get a value from a deeply-nested structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78175413/how-to-get-a-value-from-a-deeply-nested-structure)